# 2D array JSON deserializes into a string not an array

Tags: javascript, json

How can I deserialize the string of JSON below into a two-dimensional array object using JavaScript? If I use `JSON.parse` or `eval` it gets converted to a string. I'm using Douglas Crockford's [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) library.

```
[["Apples", "21529", "22457"], ["Apricots", "12547", "12559"]]
```

Comment: Works okey using eval('[["Apples", "21529", "22457"], ["Apricots", "12547", "12559"]]'). It returns me array. Check your real JSON for correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you reading the returned value? An array will convert itself to a string at the drop of a hat-, if it thinks you **want** a string. alert([1,2,3]) returns a string, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the *actual* string you're deserialising?  As per @nemisj that works for me, and more importantly it *should* work as it's the correct representation.

I suspect you may have a dangling unclosed bracket somewhere, or some other simple yet hard-to-notice problem like that, which is causing your deserialisation to fail.

In any case, this should be relatively simple to step through with Firebug (or any Javascript console using `eval`).  Just keep reducing your test input until you either end up with a minimal case that still fails and you can see what the problem is; or it suddenly starts working when you strip out a particular layer of chaff, and then you know the problem lies there.

You're certainly using Javscript correctly so there's no conceptual problem here; this is just one of those "d'oh!" issues that you need to pin down yourself.